# Dictionary help in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

Say someone was making a grade system, and they had a dictionary with each grade letter as value and a percentage as a key. How would you be able to pick a value if say, you had your key as 75% and you wanted it to print "C", but then it would still print "C" if you entered 74% or 79%.

Comment: On what basis are you defining that range?

Comment: @RohitJain what do you mean exactly?

Comment: Not sure this is the best use of a dictionary in any language. A function to calculate the grade letter may be better.

Comment: Dictionary sounds like a wrong data structure for this problem

Comment: @jsalonen -- What structure would you suggest then?  I think that a dictionary is just fine for this as long as you figure out how to mathematically map a floating point number to something which is reasonable to use as a key.

Comment: @MikeWebb -- But how do you write that function to calculate it?  Ultimately, what OP is talking about *is* a mapping which is what `dict`ionaries do.  The problem is taking a (near) infinite range and condensing it down to a discrete set of keys which is quite easy to do in this case.  IMHO, this problem is a prime candidate for `dict` use.

Comment: @mgilson dict works just fine if you can assuming you can easily define a mapping function from percentage score to a grade (division by 10 in your solution). This is not always the case.

Comment: @jsalonen -- I was just reading it and contemplating upvoting.  (I did).  It's still `O(n)` instead of a dictionary lookup which is `O(1)`.  And for the record, I wasn't saying that there weren't other ways to do it -- Just that dictionaries turn out to be a reasonably natural (and efficient) way to do it.

Comment: I don't disagree with you. Dictionary is definitely more efficient way to solve this problem. What I'm injecting here is just some common sense about the problem he is solving. Firstly, if grading function is the performance bottleneck, then it should be definitely mentioned as a requirement. Secondly, it support for uneven grading schemes is often required.

Comment: @mgilson - In my opinion, a dictionary is not simply a way to map values. In my experience standard convention seems to dictate that a dictionary is an immutable set of keys that each map to a value. The keys are constant, the values can change. By all means use it how you want, but I feel it changes the expected use of the Dictionary and would thus be better as a function.

Comment: @MikeWebb -- I'm in total agreement that this should be encapsulated in a function.  I just think that a dictionary is a natural and efficient way to implement the function (at least in the use case OP provided).

Comment: @mgilson - Granted. In relation to the question asked, your solution is a good one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use something like:

```
d = {10:'A', 9:'A', 8:'B', 7:'C', 6:'D', 5:'F', 4:'F', 3:'F', 2:'F', 1:'F', 0:'F'}
print d[int(95.0/10)]  #same as `d[95//10]`.
```

If you don't like all that typing, you could initialize your dict as:

```
d = dict(zip(range(10,-1,-1),'AABCDFFFFFF'))
```

The problem with your proposal is that you'll probably end up using floating point numbers as keys, and due to shortcomings of floating point operations, it's extremely hard to use them as dictionary keys.  This maps floats to integers and then uses those integers as keys in the dictionary which is a lot cleaner.

---

You could even be a little more clever if you wanted:

```
class GradeBook(dict):
    def __getitem__(self,key):
        return dict.__getitem__(self,key//10)

    def __missing__(self,key):
        if key > 9:
            return 'A'
        elif key < 5:
            return 'F'

d = GradeBook(zip(range(5,10),'FDCBA'))
print d[100]
print d[45]
print d[120]
print d[45.2]
print d[72.8]
```

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary -- That's a good point.  I've added that as a comment.  I would use `95//10` in my own code, but I didn't know if OP would understand the difference between `95/10` and `95//10`, so I used `int` to be more explicit.

Answer (score 4):

Doctor Livingston, I Presume.

No but really, this is not how a dictionary works.  A dictionary maps a value to a key.  What you're looking for is a function that transforms the value to a letter.

```
def grade_value(grade):
    if grade == 100:
        return "A is for Awesome!"
    if grade > 50:
        return "F is for FAILURE!!!"
```

Okay, so this isn't an actual example. But, I hope you can adapt this so it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

I would use numpy and define bins. Binning of data is a common problem.

```
import numpy as NP                                                              
grades = NP.random.randint(0, 100, 30)                                          

bins = NP.array([0., 20., 40., 60., 80., 100.])                                 

# d is an index array holding the bin id for each point in A                    
d = NP.digitize(grades, bins)                                                   
cat = ['A','B','C','D','E']                                                     
g = [cat[i-1] for i in d]                                                       

print grades,'\n'                                                               
print bins,'\n'                                                                 
print g,'\n'                                                                    

'''                                                                             
output                                                                          

[80 75 65  2 41 79 49 64 68 18 88  0 60 90 79 96 42  0 43  8  7 36 96 22 96     
 18 17 80 54 34]                                                                

[   0.   20.   40.   60.   80.  100.]                                           

['E', 'D', 'D', 'A', 'C', 'D', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'A', 'E', 'A', 'D', 'E', 'D', 'E'\
, 'C', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'E', 'B', 'E', 'A', 'A', 'E', 'C', 'B']         
'''
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using a list of tuples containing `grade, score` -pairs as this would allow you the freely specify how percentage scores are mapped into grades:

```
grades = [
    ('A', 90),
    ('B', 80),
    ('C', 70),
    ('D', 60),
    ('F', None)
]

def get_grade(score):
    return [grade for grade, grade_score in grades if score>=grade_score][0]
```

Usage:

```
print get_grade(45)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
grades = {60: 'F', 70: 'D', 80: 'C', 90: 'B', 100: 'A'}


def get_grade(percent):
    for k in sorted(grades):
        if k >= percent:
            return grades[k]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print get_grade(50)
    print get_grade(60)
    print get_grade(71)
    print get_grade(97)
```

In this case, the grade will that corresponding to the lowest key which is greater than or equal to the percentage.

Comment: This turns an O(1) dictionary lookup into an O(n) lookup.  At this point, you might as well be using a list of tuples instead of a `dict`.  Of course, that probably doesn't matter in this case, since `n` is only 5 here, but it's good to keep in mind.

Comment: @mgilson Yes, but I think that this is simplest, most obvious, least redundant, way to do it. Tuples would, as you mentioned, also work, but I don't see that being as obvious.